# How do i use the startAfter() for getting the data after the last document in the list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is how I fetch data in my postsList. How do I query the data to start after the last document in this list that i get below. What do i precisely write in the 'startAfter()' here to get the next set of list which starts after the previous list. Please be precise about it.

```
 Future<List<Post>> get posts async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsCollection
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
         .limit(30)
        .getDocuments();
    return _postListFromSnapshot(snapshot);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function you can use with a scroll controller so when the user reached towards the end of scroll then this function is called and you get the next set of data that starts after the last document as shown below.

```
     moreposts() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsCollection
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
         .startAfter([lastDocument])
         .limit(30)
        .getDocuments();

if (snapshot == null) {
return;
} 

// here you add the List with .add  if that is what you want.


      }
```